# frontend editing, show selected category

Tags: categories, frontend, category, editor

I have this in my edit form

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('jobCategory') %}
    <label for="fields[jobCategory]">Job Category:</label>
    <select id="jobCategory" name="fields[jobCategory]">
        {% for category in categories %}
            <option value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

but can't for the life of me, show select as 'selected' for the category the entry belongs to.

Missing something simple I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work. This assumes that your category field handle is 'jobCategory', and has a limit set to 1.

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('jobCategory') %}
{% set entryCategory = entry.jobCategory.first %}
<label for="fields[jobCategory]">Job Category:</label>
<select id="jobCategory" name="fields[jobCategory]">
    {% for category in categories %}
        <option value="{{ category.id }}" {% if category.title == entryCategory %}selected{% endif %}>{{ category.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: BOOM! Almost {% if category.title == entryCategory %} - if you update your answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: @StevenGrant Updated for Douglas.

Comment: Close. Glad you got it working. (And thanks brad.)